# Adding some text before and after $_POST

Tags: php, post, updates

I have this code which allows me to add information from the textarea to an existing php file (UPDATEFILE.php).

```
<?php
if ($_POST['addition']) {
    $file_open = fopen("UPDATEFILE.php", "a+");
    fwrite($file_open, $_POST['addition']);
    fclose($file_open);
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
    <textarea id="txtarea" name="addition">

    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
```

Is it possible to include something in front and behind the input to go with it?

For example, let INPUT be whatever I put into the textarea. Each time I press Submit, I want this to be added to UPDATEFILE.php

```
<div class="update">INPUT</div>
```

I'll really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Use concat. `$string = 'I am some text ' . $_POST['addition'] . ' I am ALSO some text';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by concatenating.

```
<?php
if($_POST['addition']) {
    $addition = "Before " . $_POST['addition'] . " after."

    $file_open = fopen("UPDATEFILE.php", "a+"); 
    fwrite($file_open, $addition);
    fclose($file_open);
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
    <textarea id="txtarea" name="addition">

    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
<?php
if($_POST['addition']){ 
$content = '<div class="update">INPUT</div>'.$_POST['addition']; //Add line to your existing input 
$file_open = fopen("UPDATEFILE.php","a+"); 
fwrite($file_open, $content);
fclose($file_open);
}
?>
```